# How to normalize and plot (histogram) columns of a data.table?

Tags: r, histogram

I have got a large list (20 elements, 4.2Mb) called `Buffer_list`, which I converted into a data frame (now `Buffer_norm`) like this:

```
#changing the List to a data frame with max for the biggest element
max.length <- max(sapply(Buffer_list, length))
List_norm <- lapply(Buffer_list, function(v) { c(v, rep(NA, max.length-length(v)))})
Buffer_norm <- as.data.frame(List_norm)
names(Buffer_norm) = c(1:20)
```

Every column is now of the same length (57.443 rows) with NAs for the shorter lists.

When viewing the data.frame, it shows me, that all values are numeric. The same when I try this:

```
sapply(Buffer_norm, mode)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
       14        15        16        17        18        19        20 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
> sapply(Buffer_norm, class)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
       14        15        16        17        18        19        20 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Whereas it shows me, that the values are not numeric, when

```
plot(density(Buffer_norm))
```

> Error in density.default(Buffer_norm) : argument 'x' must be numeric
>   I would like to plot a density histogram of the data.frame for every column itself with a y axis from 0 to 1. The added NAs from converting the list to a data.frame have to be kept in mind!

I tried to follow this: [R Normalize then plot two histograms together in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287614/r-normalize-then-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r/29291172) 
and [ggplot2 histogram with density curve that sums to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412805/ggplot2-histogram-with-density-curve-that-sums-to-1?rq=1)
without any success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Buffer_norm` is a dataset, you must select one variable. Please check this example with `mtcars` data.

```
str(mtcars)
plot(density(mtcars))
 Error in density.default(mtcars) : argument 'x' must be numeric
plot(density(mtcars[, 1]))
```

[image]

Comment: `> plot(density(Buffer_norm[,1]))
Error in density.default(Buffer_norm[, 1]) : 'x' contains missing values` it does not work either

Comment: plot(density(Buffer_norm[,1])) Error in density.default(!is.na(Buffer_norm[, 1]))

Comment: if I use `!is.na` the error x has to be numeric occurs and if I use `na.rm=TRUE` "Error in density.default(Buffer_norm[, 1]) : 'x' contains missing values".     So acutally both is not working....

Comment: Would you like to put here a link to the data?

Comment: By not just selecting the right colomn, but also the rows until the NAs start, it works now! like this: `plot(density(Buffer_DF[1:26208,1]))`